# Can't connect to Tor due to read server hello

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, error

```
12/12/2016 14:38:46 PM.100 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/12/2016 14:38:50 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/12/2016 14:38:50 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/12/2016 14:38:50 PM.800 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/12/2016 14:38:50 PM.800 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/12/2016 14:38:55 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
12/12/2016 14:38:55 PM.700 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
12/12/2016 14:38:56 PM.000 [WARN] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server. (DONE; DONE; count 1; recommendation warn; host B9E7141C594AF25699E0079C1F0146F409495296 at 0.0.2.0:2) 
12/12/2016 14:38:56 PM.000 [WARN] 1 connections have failed: 
12/12/2016 14:38:56 PM.000 [WARN]  1 connections died in state handshaking (TLS) with SSL state SSLv2/v3 read server hello A in HANDSHAKE 
12/12/2016 14:38:57 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing no-longer-configured Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
12/12/2016 14:38:57 PM.200 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
12/12/2016 14:38:57 PM.200 [NOTICE] Closing old Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150
```

Comment: Possibly blocking meek-amazon, try meek-azure. Also possibly just a bad connection.